# Is there any way to get check if certain domain exists in Common Crawl?

Tags: common-crawl

I want to know if certain domain is exists in common crawl’s crawl data. Is there any API or any other way to check that?

I couldn’t find any way to achieve this in their documentations

In my solution I need find out weather specific domain’s data is exists or not So your help will really appreciate. Thanks